# Careers Top X% - Should be able to choose which (multiple) SE sites are shown

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs

I'm a system administrator. While my Stack Overflow tags are applicable to my career skills, I'd also like to show my top tags on Server Fault and possibly other SE sites.

Could additional sites be user selectable to show in the Top X% section on our Careers 2.0 listings?

Comment: As a member who is active on other sites, I feel very excluded because of this.